# Get HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse from Camel Message Body

Tags: java, apache-camel, jetty

I'm trying to send a request to an HTTP endpoint using Camel Jetty or Camel HTTP component. I was wondering if it's possible to convert the request and response to HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects.

I have the following route:

```
from("direct://processing/callEndpoint")
    .to("jetty:http://www.google.com")
    .to("bean:processHttpResponse")
```

I'm using Guice for dependency injection and *"bean:processHttpResponse"* is the following:

```
public class HttpResponseBean {

    public void processResponse(Exchange exchange) {

        HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse response = exchange.getOut().getBody(HttpServletResponse.class);

    }
}
```

Both *request* and *response* objects are null. When debugging/inspecting the Exchange, the In Message is a byte array (byte[]) and the Out Message is null. Not sure how to proceed..

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Camel Jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) goto the Consumer Example.

Try to call your bean like this.

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:{{port}}/myapp/myservice").bean(HttpResponseBean,"processResponse");

public class HttpResponseBean {

    public void processResponse(Exchange exchange) {

         // we have access to the HttpServletRequest here and we can grab it if we need it
            HttpServletRequest req = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: The .bean() format (instead of .to("bean:") didn't work. I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a processor like this one:

```
public class MyBean implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse response = exchange.getOut().getBody(HttpServletResponse.class);
    }
}
```

If you have a `@Configuration` Spring context like this

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    return new MyBean();
  }

}
```

you should be able to refer to it in the `process` statement like this `.process("bean:myBean")`.

If you are building your route using a RouteBuilder, please use a `SpringCamelContext` in order to let Camel access the beans.